# Datasheets, dimensioning questions

Tags: rf, analog, datasheet, potentiometer, ham-radio

I have a problem reading [this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/13/RV24AF-1658492.pdf) datasheet.

[image]

This one is very weird, does 3-1.5 mean that pin is 3 mm wide, and 1.5 mm is meant to be a radius, or does it mean 1.5 mm and that that 3 means three pins?

[image]

Now from this picture I assume that pins are not circular. So the pins are 1.5 mm wide, and 0.5 mm thick, am I right?
[image]
Now here it says 1.7-3holes. I assume this means 1.7 mm diameter for 3 holes, and not that diameter can be anything between 1.7 and 3 mm, right? However, using - sign here is strange.

2.5/2 mm, I assume this means that left measurement is 2.5 mm (between first and second pin), and 2 mm is between the second pin and something else on the potentiometer's casing, am I right?

I am very sorry for bothering you with such basic and dumb questions, but it's the first time I'm creating my own footpring, and I am a little in hurry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 3 means all three pins are identical, all 1.5 wide, 0.5 deep, all holes 1.7 diameter.

The 2 is distance to the mounting surface, you just cut it out from the picture but it reads in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

"3-1.5" probably means that all three pins are 1.5 wide, end to end.

"1.7-3HOLES" means just what you think it means -- 3 Holes, all 1.7 diameter.

The 2.5/2 part is horrible nonstandard dimensioning technique, and is quite annoying.  My assumption is that the front pair of leads is 2.5 from the middle lead, which is 2 from the mounting surface.

Comment: No need to assume, the same information is duplicated in the side view, which is bad dimensioning practice. Really mediocre drawing.